# How to getchildren text and set that in list view

Tags: java, android, firebase

I've been trying to get the children list in list view in my dashboard. Whenever I click users I need this children to be listed in a list view.

[My Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPEQA.png)

```
    ClientsRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");


    ClientsRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if(dataSnapshot.exists())
            {
                clientcount=(int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                Clients.setText(Integer.toString(clientcount));

            }
            else
                {
                    Clients.setText("0 Clients");

            }

        }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far in code?

Comment: i literally have no idea , i can able to get the count only by using getChildrenCount function

Comment: Edit the question and add that code.

Answer (score 0):

Create one model class having all field as fields of your database child and use it like below

=> Suppose your model class name is **Users** then...

```
 ClientsRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if(dataSnapshot.exists())
            {
                 Users users=new Users(dataSnapshot.getValue());
                 ArrayList<Users> userList=new ArrayList();
                 userList.add(users);

            }
            else
                {
                Clients.setText("0 Clients");

            }

        }
```

Comment: i think you didnt understand what im asking, i want to settext the children itself, not the database under the numbrer,

Comment: so for that you must want to take textview of numbers of your children count..m i right ?

Comment: then why you don't use recyclerView to achieve your functionality ?

Comment: can you pls guide to the whole process if you understood my query

Comment: Are you familiar with RecyclerView and RecyclerView Adapter ?

Comment: yes but i have no idea how to implement this here, guide me out man

Answer (score 0):

[1]. Just take **recyclerview** instead of TextView in your activity.

[2]. Take an ArrayList of String into your activity like

```
ArrayList<String> childList=new ArrayList<>();
```

[3]. Create an Adapter for your recyclerview in which in item layout file add just one textView in which you will display your children list.

[4]. Set that adapter with recyclerView in onCreate()like my below code

```
recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false);
YourAdapter adapter=new YourAdapter(this,childList) //pass your arraylist
recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

[5]. in onDataChange() make changes as below

```
ClientsRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if(dataSnapshot.exists())
            {
               for(DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot){
                 childList.add(snapshot.getKey());
               }
               adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            else
                {
                Clients.setText("0 Clients");

            }

        }
```

**THAT'S IT**

Comment: Sir see this one ,https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=58I0_sp9uBg&t=71s you'll understand what i want excatly